# Python и multiprocessing Pool зашел в тупик

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

Всем доброго времени суток зашел в тупик со скриптом. Подскажите как передать название файла который записывается в цикле в переменную **ListUrl** в функцию **fun**?

```
resultUrl = sorted(glob.glob("*.csv")) # Получаю список файлов csv
for ListUrl in resultUrl:
  list = list_url(ListUrl) # Собираю список из url из файла csv
  with Pool(10) as p: # Создаю пул
    p.map(fun, list) # Отправляю url в функцию. В функции отправляю http запрос собираю данные и записываю в файл
  Email(ListUrl) # Отправляю отчет на email
```

Comment: В подобных затруднениях может помочь чтение [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map). Зачем `for` если используется `map`? Что попадает в `resultUrl`, какое преобразование делает функция `list_url`? Вашему примеру не хватает воспроизводимости и вы не пишете, что конкретно хотите получить на выходе. Почитайте, пожалуйста, [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и про [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать, например, `partial`. Обратите внимание, что "прошиваемый" через `partial` параметр идёт вторым у функции, иначе работать не будет:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def fun(lst, fname):
    print(fname, lst)

...
fun_fname = partial(fun, fname=ListUrl)
with Pool(10) as p: # Создаю пул
  p.map(fun_fname, list)
```

Кстати, `list` - это плохое название переменной, оно перекрывает встроенный питоновский объект `list`, не надо так делать.